# How to use an API URL and get XML Information to display

Tags: php, xml, api, url, xml-parsing

I have a site that currently has a list of 'available pets' for adoption.

This site has recently begun listing their pets on petfinder.com - petfinder has an API that I have been able to use to get just the pets I want by using a URL.

My question is - how do I integrate those results onto the 'available pets' page?

I tried this:

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://api.petfinder.com/shelter.getPets?key=ourkey&id=ourid&status=A&output=full');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

But it didn't give me any results on the page.
The results are in XML format - which is fine for now - I can dig up how to format that stuff with PHP later.  Right now I'm just trying to get the results to display on the page.

Any ideas?  I'm sure this is a simple one, I just don't have a lot of experience with this stuff and am trying to learn.

Comment: Edited for clarity - Sorry about that - forgot to put it in code tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a snippet of bad syntax in my php:

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://api.petfinder.com/shelter.getPets?key=ourkey&id=ourid&status=A&output=full');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

Ended up working fine once I corrected the syntax error I had.  Onto figuring out how to play with the XML within PHP :-D